# Are there any methods in .NET BCL which take `ref` parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters

`TryParse` family of methods uses `out` parameters; I could give `Swap` as an example of `ref` parameters being useful, but are there good examples in the .NET Base Class Library?

Comment: @JaredPar: Another name for BCL I suspect :)

Comment: I'm 100% sure, based on the c# tag and mention of the TryParse methods (which are methods on BCL structs), that alexey_r was using FCL as a synonym for the .NET BCL. Though in retrospect, I shouldn't have rolled back, I should have re-edited.

Comment: "BCL" basically means "stuff in System namespace".  "FCL" means "stuff in System and Microsoft namespaces".  Most people are, understandably, not at all careful about the exact nuances of the distinction when speaking casually.

Comment: @John "FCL" == Microsoft *F*oundation *C*lass *L*brary.  Yes it was a stretch :)

Comment: FCL = Framework Class Library which includes BCL.

Comment: See this link which shows what is part of FCL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few just in mscorlib. Run this to find them, and give it types in different assemblies to show others.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowRefsInAssemblyContaining(typeof(string));
    }

    static void ShowRefsInAssemblyContaining(Type exampleType)
    {
        var query = from type in exampleType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                    where type.IsPublic
                    from method in type.GetMethods()
                    where method.GetParameters()
                                .Any(p => p.ParameterType.IsByRef &&
                                         !p.IsOut)
                    select method;

        foreach (var method in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType + ": " + method);
        }
    }
}
```

Simplest example: [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx).

(Don't you love LINQ, btw?)

Comment: LINQ == COOL

Didn't know this was possible!!

Comment: Note that it shows both `ref` and `out` parameter methods since CLR doesn't distinguish them, only C# compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant in the base class libraries...

If so, there are various locations that take ref parameters.  One example is [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a.aspx) in System.Threading.